# ViewGroup clip children by background shape

Tags: android

I have `ViewGroup` with background (xml shape with round corners).

How to clip the children by the background shape?

In the picture you see the top bar overlaps the corner.

[image]

Should be like this:

[image]

Comment: is that a custom viewgroup?

Comment: constraintlayout